# C# Linq - Matching two sets of data and updating the first set on a match

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a `Person` class as below where I have two instances of a `Person` collection, the first instance is the master collection containing all records whereas the second instance is a subset of the master collection.

What I need to do is update the IsMatched property of the master set where the instance also exists in the subset.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsMatched { get; set; }
}
```

Can Enumerable [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) be use to match and update the master data set?

Based on Tim's suggest I create a unit test to test the solution

```
 [TestFixture()]
    public class Test
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class MatchedSetTest
        {
            private class Person
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }

                public string Title { get; set; }

                public string FirstName { get; set; }

                public string LastName { get; set; }

                public bool IsMatched { get; set; }
            }

            [Test]
            public void TestMatchingSets()
            {
                var members = new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Smith", Id = 1, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Paul", LastName = "Jones", Id = 2, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Thompson", Id = 3, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Simon", LastName = "Green", Id = 4, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Phil", LastName = "Stuart", Id = 5, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Sean", LastName = "Appleton", Id = 6, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false}
                };

                var buddy = new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Smith", Id = 1, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Gary", LastName = "Thompson", Id = 3, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false} ,
                    new Person() { FirstName = "Simon", LastName = "Green", Id = 4, Title = "Mr", IsMatched = false}
                };

                var existing = from m in members
                               join s in buddy on m.Id equals s.Id
                               select new { Master = m, Subset = s };

                foreach (var both in existing)
                {
                    both.Master.IsMatched = both.Subset.IsMatched;
                }

            var p = existing.Where(w => w.Master.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault().Master;
            Assert.IsTrue(p.IsMatched);

            }

        }

    }
```

The existing object contained the three items from the subset with a Master and Subset instance within and the IsMatched properties for all instances was still False.

What I require is that the entire Master collection is returned with the matching items from the subset flagging the IsMatched property to true on the matching Master collection instance.

**Another Option**

Would this be an appropriate solution?

```
buddy.ForEach(b =>
{
    var member = members.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Id == b.Id);

    if (member != null)
        member.IsMatched = true;
});
```

Comment: How much entries do these collections contain ?

Comment: The master set contains perhaps 9000 rows whereas the subset may contain 50-100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them, store both in an anonymous type and then use a foreach:

```
var existing = from m in master join s in subset on m.Id equals s.Id 
               select new { Master = m, Subset = s };
foreach (var both in existing)
{
    both.Master.IsMatched = both.Subset.IsMatched;
}
```

Note that this presumes that there is only one subset for each master. If you have duplicates the result could be arbitrary because the last subset-person wins.

Comment: Thanks Tim but the IsMatched property appears to be false for all the entities within the existing anonymous type both before and after the ForEach. How do you get a master collection from the anonymous type with the IsMatched set to true?

Comment: It also appear to only return the matched Person instances from the subset collection

Comment: I think that in foreach loop you need to use the following code both.Master.IsMatched = true

Answer (score 0):

Use in your unit test

```
 var existing = from m in members
                join s in buddy on m.Id equals s.Id
                select new { Master = m, Subset = s };

 foreach (var both in existing)
 {
     both.Master.IsMatched = true;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

The snippet below will return only the records in `personListA` that exist in `personListB` and where the matched record in `personListB` has `IsMatched` set to true (matching records is based on the `Id` property).

```
personListA.Where(pla => personListB.Any(plb => plb.Id == pla.Id && plb.IsMatched));
```

[Working Demo in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jxf3vI)

Comment: Returns no matches.

Comment: Added a link to a working demo. It will only return matches if both lists have a person with the same Id and the instance in personListB has IsMatched set to true.